# Bootstrap button with edit text and icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Can I use it to have a button with Edit text and icon inside it ?

Comment: Please explain _'button with Edit text'_.

Comment: you want button text editable? like `ContentEditable="true"`

Comment: Why not just look at the [Documentation for 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons)? How do you get to 8k+ and still ask this type of question?

Comment: This can be closed as "Needs Clarity". Requests for clarification were made, but the question was not updated.

Answer (score 2):

Edit like this?

```
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
```

Comment: +1 For only answer that actually used v2.3.2. Here's a [2.3 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/jE9C3/), although I bet OP actually wants `icon-pencil`

Answer (score -1):

`<button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</button>`

Like that? else i'm not sure i understand your question

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/4DXsM/)

Comment: -1 Not valid for version 2.3.2.  Try to run it in this [2.3.2 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/jE9C3/). See [2.3.2 docs for more info](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons)

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost that version is old. But according to the [Bootstrap's Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) you can for example

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
```

Comment: -1 Not valid for version 2.3.2.  Try to run it in this [2.3 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/jE9C3/).  See [2.3 docs for more info](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons)